# Mock class which inherit from abstract class and implements interface

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nsubstitute

Assume following scenario: I have a `PhoneController` class which use `Phone` class. `Phone` is a class which inherit from abstract class `Device` and it implements `IPhone` interface. For testing `PhoneController` I want to mock `Phone` class, but I don't know how it might be done using NSubstitute, because `Phone` class inherits abstract class and additionally it implements interface.

Example code:

```
public abstract class Device
{
    protected string Address { get; set; }
}

public interface IPhone
{
    void MakeCall();
}

public class Phone : Device, IPhone
{
    public void MakeCall()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class PhoneController
{
    private Phone _phone;

    public PhoneController(Phone phone)
    {
        _phone = phone;
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class PhoneControllerTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        // How mock Phone class? 
        //var mock = Substitute.For<Device, IPhone>();

        //usage of mock
        //var controller = new PhoneController(mock);
    }
}
```

## Second scenario:

Controller uses `GetStatus` method from `Device` abstract class, so `_phone` cannot be changed to `IPhone` type

```
public abstract class Device
{
    protected string Address { get; set; }

    public abstract string GetStatus();
}

public interface IPhone
{
    void MakeCall();
}

public class Phone : Device, IPhone
{
    public void MakeCall()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override string GetStatus()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class PhoneController
{
    private Phone _phone;

    public PhoneController(Phone phone)
    {
        _phone = phone;
    }

    public string GetDeviceStatus()
    {
        return _phone.GetStatus();
    }

    public void MakeCall()
    {
        _phone.MakeCall();
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class PhoneControllerTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        // How mock Phone class? 
        //var mock = Substitute.For<Device, IPhone>();

        //usage of mock
        //var controller = new PhoneController(mock);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `PhoneController` takes a `Phone`, then you will have to use a `Phone` or a subclass of `Phone`. Using `Substitute.For<Device, IPhone>()` will generate a type a bit like this:

```
public class Temp : Device, IPhone { ... }
```

Which is not the same as a `Phone`.

So there are a few options. Ideally I'd consider [@pm_2's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50276624/nsubstitute-mock-class-which-inherit-from-abstract-class-and-implements-interfac/50276788#50276788) of making `PhoneController` take an `IPhone` instead. By making it depend on an interface rather than something concrete we gain some flexibility: `PhoneController` now can work with anything that adheres to the `IPhone` interface, including a mocked `IPhone` instance. This also means we can change the behaviour of production code by have other implementations (contrived example, maybe an `EncryptedPhone : IPhone` that encrypts the call, without requiring a change to `PhoneController`).

If you do need to couple the specific `Phone` class to `PhoneController`, then mocking immediately becomes more difficult. After all, you are stating "this only works with this specific class", then trying to get it working with another class (the substituted class). For this approach, if you are able to make all the relevant members of the `Phone` class `virtual` then you can create a substitute using `Substitute.For<Phone>()`. If you need to also need to run some of the original `Phone` code, but substitute other parts, then you can using `Substitute.ForPartsOf<Phone>()` as [@pm_2 suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50276624/nsubstitute-mock-class-which-inherit-from-abstract-class-and-implements-interfac/50276788#50276788). Remember that NSubstitute (and many other .NET mocking libraries) will not mock non-`virtual` members, so keep this in mind when mocking classes.

Finally, it is worth considering not mocking `Phone` at all and using the real class instead. If `PhoneController` depends on the details of specific `Phone` implementation, then testing it with a fake version is not going to tell you whether it works. If instead it only needs a compatible interface, then it is a good candidate for using a substitute. Mocking libraries automate the creation of an alternative type to use with a class, but they will not automate having a design that accommodates the use of that type. :)

### Edit for second scenario

I think my previous answer still applies for the additional scenario. To recap: my first approach is to attempt to decouple the `PhoneController` from a specific implementation; then I'd consider substituting for `Phone` directly (with the disclaimer about non-`virtual` methods). And I'd always keep in mind not mocking at all (this should probably be the first option).

There are many ways we can achieve the first option. We could update `PhoneController` to take an `IDevice` (extract interface from `Device`) and an `IPhone`, with the constructor `PhoneController(IPhone p, IDevice d)`. The real code can then be:

```
var phone = new Phone();
var controller = new PhoneController(phone, phone);
```

While the test code could be:

```
var phone = Substitute.For<IPhone>();
var device = Substitute.For<IDevice>();
var testController = new PhoneController(phone, device);
// or
var phone = Substitute.For<IPhone, IDevice>();
var testController = new PhoneController(phone, (IDevice) phone);
```

Alternatively we could create `IPhone`, `IDevice` and then have:

```
interface IPhoneDevice : IPhone, IDevice { }
public class Phone : IPhoneDevice { ... }
```

I've seen interface inheritance like this discouraged before, so you may want to look into that first before taking this option.

You can also combine these approaches, by replacing `IDevice` in the examples above with your current `Device` base class and mocking that (disclaimer: non-`virtual`s).

I think the main question you need to answer is how to you want to couple `PhoneController` to its dependencies? Think about this in terms of what concrete dependencies does it need, and what can be expressed in terms of logical interfaces. The answer to that will determine your options for testing.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change _phone type to IPhone, please see my updated question, below "Second scenario: header

Comment: I think my answer still applies. :) I've updated to be more specific to your second scenario.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of ways to do this, and which one you choose depends what you're trying to test.

1. You can mock the IPhone interface (as you have done in your commented out code.
2. You can subclass the Phone class (either manually, or use NSubstitute's [`.ForPartsOf<>`](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/partial-subs/)).  See [here](https://www.pmichaels.net/2018/03/22/using-nsubstitute-for-partial-mocks/) for a blog post on this.

I find that if I structure my test using the Arrange/Act/Assert method, it's clearer what I'm trying to test (ideally there should be a single call in your Act section; for example:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    // Arrange
    var mock = Substitute.For<IPhone>();
    var controller = new PhoneController(mock);

    // Act
    int result = controller.Method();

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal(result, 3);
}
```

EDIT - Based on updated comments

You can't unit test an abstract class, because that class doesn't contain (by definition) any code.  In your scenario, it looks like what you're trying to do is to test the concrete `Phone` class.  If that's the case, then simply create an instance of the `Phone` class and test it; you don't need to involve the controller:

```
// Arrange
var phone = new Phone();

// Act
string result = phone.GetStatus();

// Assert
Assert.Equal("New", result);
```

Comment: What if Phone class override some method from abstract class and controller uses this overrided method? In this situation I cannot change `_phone` field to be of type IPhone

Comment: Why not?  There's no reason that you can't change the constructor parameter in your code to be an IPhone instead of Phone and pass a mock in.  If you're trying to test the Phone class, then arguably you you be better doing that separately.  It largely depends on exactly what you're trying to test.

Comment: because I want to be able to use methods from abstract class, please see me updated question above "Second scenario" header

Comment: I agree with your updated answer - yes, it looks like controller only uses methods from phone class, but I wrote code like this, because I wanted omit unnecessary details of controller, thus I should test controller